# Getting "Force Close" with my first HelloWorldLogin android code

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I was trying to learn by following the lab here https://sites.google.com/site/androidcoursearchive/labs/lab-1

Here's the code

**NameGetter.java**

```
public class NameGetter extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText name;
    Button submit;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.name_getter);
        name = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        submit = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String userName = name.getText().toString();
        Intent submitIntent = new Intent(NameGetter.this, HelloWorld.class);
        submitIntent.putExtra("username", userName);
        this.startActivity(submitIntent);
    }
}
```

**HelloWorld.java**

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textViewHello);

        Bundle name = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        if(name != null) {
            String nameEntered = name.getString("username");
            if(nameEntered != null) {
                tv.setText(nameEntered);
            } else {
                tv.setText("nameEntered is null");
            }
        } else {
            tv.setText("name is null");
        }
    }
}
```

I can enter the text into the EditText box,and when I press submit button I get a forced close. LogCat says as following:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackagerhello.com/com.mypackagerhello.com.HelloWorld}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

EDIT: Thank you all! It was the `this.setContentView(R.layout.main);` line that was missing from HelloWorld.java.

Comment: Have you declared HelloWorld in your maanifest?

Comment: where is the setContentView(R.layout.); HelloWorld ??

Comment: I suppose you are assuming that the same UI is shared between two activities, which is wrong.
Two activities use their own UI so you have to call setContentView(R.layout.name_getter); in HelloWorld Class just after super.onCreate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that in your NameGetter Activity you set the content view like so:

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.name_getter);
```

but in your HelloWorld activity you haven't done so. Add that line right after super.onCreate and before findViewById. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Insert

```
setContentView(R.layout.<layout_id>);
```

in the HelloWorld  before

```
TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textViewHello);
```